# What is the best way to offset previous posts on the same page?

Tags: wp-query, offsets

I have some main pages with multiple custom query like :

all posts with filter X,
all posts with filter Y,

etc...

I would like to make a last query for ALL posts, but exclude or offset all the posts already listed in previous queries.

I have two ideas, but I wish to have your advice on best practices, even with a third approach.

1. stock posts #ID in my previous queries and stock them
2. get posts #ID in my #container in JS and stock them

Then use post not in with those ID's.

But this will make at least 30 or 40 id's to stock and add in post not in.

Am I on the good way ? Or do you have any better idea ?